# Plugging in an external DVD drive causes ls, sudo, new SSH connections refused.... what happened?

Tags: drivers, raspberry-pi, debugging, dvd, peripherals

Title says it all. But I plugged in an external DVD drive into my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. It says its Linux compatible

However when I actually plug it into the device. Everything goes wrong in incomprehensible ways.

SSH says "kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer. Connection reset by 192.168.50.2 port 22"

Or when I do "ls" it says "-bash: /usr/bin/ls: Input/output error"

Or when I do "sudo" it says "-bash: sudo: command not found"

Nothing really works with it plugged in.

However when I reboot the RaspberryPi all is well... up until I plug in the DVD drive.

What is going on? How can I troubleshoot or fix it given so many commands are down? What might've happened?

**Investigation updates**
$PATH
Before `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`
After - Same
BUT this is odd to me. This is a newly configured version of the OS. Why is it pointing to games and all of these other things? Odd?

DVD drive "hyripe external cd/dvd drive"

Another thing that seems potentially relevant. Device is booting and using an external SSD plugged in via a USB port as memory.

dmesg output

```
[   19.657310] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[   87.772696] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[   87.775097] device offline error, dev sda, sector 135274584 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[   87.775132] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 16777227, lost async page write
[   87.775164] device offline error, dev sda, sector 177217664 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[   87.775179] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 22020112, lost async page write
[   87.775195] device offline error, dev sda, sector 177221200 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[   87.775208] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 22020554, lost async page write
[   87.775223] device offline error, dev sda, sector 177221456 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[   87.775236] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 22020586, lost async page write
[   87.775250] device offline error, dev sda, sector 177225992 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[   87.775262] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 22021153, lost async page write
[   87.775276] device offline error, dev sda, sector 177309888 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[   87.775288] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 22031640, lost async page write
[   87.775302] device offline error, dev sda, sector 1056768 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[   87.775314] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 0, lost async page write
[   87.775328] device offline error, dev sda, sector 1056840 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[   87.775340] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 9, lost async page write
[   87.775354] device offline error, dev sda, sector 1056856 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[   87.775366] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 11, lost async page write
[   87.776903] device offline error, dev sda, sector 123307176 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x9800 phys_seg 3 prio class 2
[   87.776946] Aborting journal on device sda2-8.
[   87.777003] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 15237120, lost sync page write
[   87.777038] JBD2: I/O error when updating journal superblock for sda2-8.
[   87.778325] EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_journal_check_start:84: comm systemd-journal: Detected aborted journal
[   87.778377] EXT4-fs (sda2): previous I/O error to superblock detected
[   87.780733] EXT4-fs (sda2): I/O error while writing superblock
[   87.780759] EXT4-fs (sda2): Remounting filesystem read-only
[   87.932676] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[   87.946770] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): dx_probe:822: inode #4194305: lblock 0: comm wf-panel-pi: error -5 reading directory block
[   87.960681] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): dx_probe:822: inode #11752: lblock 0: comm wf-panel-pi: error -5 reading directory block
[   87.960788] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): dx_probe:822: inode #11752: lblock 0: comm wf-panel-pi: error -5 reading directory block
[   87.996669] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): dx_probe:822: inode #4194305: lblock 0: comm gvfs-udisks2-vo: error -5 reading directory block
[   87.996739] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): dx_probe:822: inode #4194305: lblock 0: comm gvfs-udisks2-vo: error -5 reading directory block
[   87.997338] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): dx_probe:822: inode #4194305: lblock 0: comm gvfs-udisks2-vo: error -5 reading directory block
[   88.036652] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x07 driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   88.036752] scsi 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to dead device
[   88.036853] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): dx_probe:822: inode #4194305: lblock 0: comm gvfs-udisks2-vo: error -5 reading directory block
[   88.036936] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): dx_probe:822: inode #4194305: lblock 0: comm gvfs-udisks2-vo: error -5 reading directory block
[   88.036961] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): dx_probe:822: inode #4194305: lblock 0: comm gvfs-udisks2-vo: error -5 reading directory block
[   88.036980] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): dx_probe:822: inode #4194305: lblock 0: comm gvfs-udisks2-vo: error -5 reading directory block
[   89.272857] usb usb2-port1: over-current change #1
[   89.347052] usb 1-1-port1: over-current change #1
[   89.488839] usb usb2-port2: over-current change #1
[   89.567467] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change #1
[   89.704835] usb usb2-port3: over-current change #1
[   89.785661] usb 1-1-port3: over-current change #1
[   89.920848] usb usb2-port4: over-current change #1
[   90.005647] usb 1-1-port4: over-current change #1
[   91.216972] usb usb2-port1: over-current change #2
[   91.432929] usb usb2-port2: over-current change #2
[   91.648944] usb usb2-port3: over-current change #2
[   91.864930] usb usb2-port4: over-current change #2
[   92.353317] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[   92.381049] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=9210, bcdDevice=20.01
[   92.381060] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   92.381064] usb 2-2: Product: RTL9210
[   92.381068] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Realtek
[   92.381071] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 012345678904
[   92.386529] usb 2-2: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[   92.387180] usb 2-2: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[   92.396633] usb 2-2: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[   92.397227] usb 2-2: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[   92.400265] scsi host1: uas
[   92.403800] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Realtek  RTL9210 NVME     1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[   92.434380] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[   92.439587] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 250069680 512-byte logical blocks: (128 GB/119 GiB)
[   92.441039] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[   92.441052] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 37 00 00 08
[   92.444215] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[   92.445600] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Preferred minimum I/O size 512 bytes
[   92.445610] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
[   92.456256]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
[   92.456687] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[   93.009059] EXT4-fs warning: 152 callbacks suppressed
[   93.009080] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): dx_probe:822: inode #4194305: lblock 0: comm gmain: error -5 reading directory block
[   93.946572] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): dx_probe:822: inode #4194305: lblock 0: comm wf-panel-pi: error -5 reading directory block
[   93.946708] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): dx_probe:822: inode #11752: lblock 0: comm wf-panel-pi: error -5 reading directory block
[   93.946748] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): dx_probe:822: inode #11752: lblock 0: comm wf-panel-pi: error -5 reading directory block
[   93.996856] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[   94.097995] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=13fd, idProduct=1040, bcdDevice= 1.06
[   94.098020] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   94.098032] usb 1-1.4: Product: UJDA755 DVD/CDRW
[   94.098042] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Initio
[   94.098050] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 0000000000000000W
[   94.102518] usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   94.104036] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0
[   94.947221] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): dx_probe:822: inode #4194305: lblock 0: comm wf-panel-pi: error -5 reading directory block
[   94.947358] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): dx_probe:822: inode #11752: lblock 0: comm wf-panel-pi: error -5 reading directory block
[   94.947400] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): dx_probe:822: inode #11752: lblock 0: comm wf-panel-pi: error -5 reading directory block
[   95.009150] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): dx_probe:822: inode #4194305: lblock 0: comm gmain: error -5 reading directory block
[   95.197299] scsi 2:0:0:0: CD-ROM            MATSHITA UJDA755 DVD/CDRW 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[   95.198097] scsi 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[   95.198889] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): htree_dirblock_to_tree:1082: inode #4195975: lblock 0: comm systemd-udevd: error -5 reading directory block
[   95.199149] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): htree_dirblock_to_tree:1082: inode #11102: lblock 0: comm systemd-udevd: error -5 reading directory block
[   96.695423] usb usb2-port1: over-current change #3
[   96.909249] usb usb2-port2: over-current change #3
[   97.126132] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[   97.156984] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[   97.384973] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x07 driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   97.685449] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[   97.713108] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=9210, bcdDevice=20.01
[   97.713134] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   97.713147] usb 2-2: Product: RTL9210
[   97.713157] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Realtek
[   97.713166] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 012345678904
[   97.716723] usb 2-2: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[   97.717440] usb 2-2: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[   98.256005] usb 2-2: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[   98.256581] usb 2-2: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[   98.262045] EXT4-fs warning: 73 callbacks suppressed
[   98.262062] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): htree_dirblock_to_tree:1082: inode #4195975: lblock 0: comm systemd-udevd: error -5 reading directory block
[   98.262332] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): htree_dirblock_to_tree:1082: inode #11102: lblock 0: comm systemd-udevd: error -5 reading directory block
[   98.262441] EXT4-fs warning (device sda2): dx_probe:822: inode #4194305: lblock 0: comm systemd-udevd: error -5 reading directory block
[   98.262888] scsi host1: uas
```

Comment: Does the external DVD drive use its own power supply? Or is it connected via a USB hub with its own power supply?

Comment: In line with @KamilMaciorowski's comment: Is your OS'es drive (presuming `sdb` here) also using a USB port since this is a Pi?  The issue here as Kamil has picked up on is `overcurrent`.  See seconds 89 -91.  See the [Pi Forums: External DVD](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=189977)

Answer (score 0):

This is a **guess**, but I suspect if you change your plug arrangement to use a USB hub - instead of plugging the DVD directly into a USB port on the RPi - that your problems will disappear.

FWIW, you've not given us much to go on: no model #, no OS version, no info on power supply, no info on DVD current requirements, etc.